# File auditing software for Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, security

I am looking for a program or program suite that will allow the auditing of network shared resources (specifically storage space), and render reports (who created, deleted, moved, modified files, etc).

Yes, I know I can turn on auditing on Windows, but the Event Log isn't quite the "charmer" for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Directory Monitor: http://www.deventerprise.net/Projects.aspx. I use it to keep logs on student file access. Much simpler/cleaner than file auditing.

Comment: Nice application.

Comment: I don't think this shows _who_ made changes though...

Answer (score 1):

Directory Monitor is in the process of being upgraded to support detecting the user who made the changes.

A summary of other highlighted changes (including making it a service to be more friendly to server platforms without user interactivity) can be found in [this article](http://brutaldev.com/post/2011/01/05/Directory-Monitor-20-Release-Roadmap.aspx) along with a link to the issue tracker.

**UPDATE**: User detection is available in Directory Monitor now.
Disclaimer: I am the product developer and just want to keep this question up to date with what is currently available.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Quest as well. Pretty decent product, already does user-level tracking and reporting.

http://www.quest.com/changeauditor-for-windows-file-servers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quotas for storage space. It is in the File Server Management Snap In under "File Server Resource Manager"

It is an amazing tool for notifying admins and users about current disk space. You can set hard and soft limits and send emails out to Admins and offending users.

Don't know if it can do any more auditing than that. But you should definitely check it out. May be all you need.